# How to use previous result that is made with previous row value in current row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to ask about the way how to use to use previous result that is made with previous row value in current row.

For example,

[image]

I want to make new column 'NUM2' in main query.

As you can see in the image, SECOND row's NUM2 is made with 3 * 2(FIRST row's NUM2)

And, THIRD row's NUM1 is made with 6 * 6(SECOND row's NUM2, this value is the result of 3 * 2(FIRST row's NUM2))

When I first met this problem, I thought that if I can use variable, I can solve this problem.

But I don't know how to use variable in DML situation.

If you give me some advice, I really appreciate it.

(I'm using oracle 11g)

Comment: You can't seriously consider using string values like 'FIRST', 'SECOND' etc. in a string column to ***order*** the rows, can you? Other than that - please create a slightly longer input (with four rows, for example); use a meaningful ordering method (for example, instead of a string column named `name`, use a numeric column named `seq` or `ord`), and show the output you want to get from that input.

Comment: You can use the analytical function LAG to access data in the previous rows of the resultset - does that help you ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie I just edited this post adding a image. So can you answer this question for me?

Comment: @mathguy I just edited this post adding a image. So can you answer this question for me?

Comment: I will repeat my question. You need to be able to use the ordering column in an `order by` question. What ordering allows you to get `FIRST` as first, `SECOND` as second, `THIRD` as third, `FOURTH` as fourth, etc.? This is just crazy. Can't you use numbers (1, 2, 3, 4) like everyone else? Other than that, the problem is not that difficult. Where does the value 2 in the `NUM2` column come from? Do you pass it in, perhaps as a bind variable?

Comment: @mathguy Sorry. 'ORDER' column can have numbers as you said. Please consider FIRST as 1, SECOND as 2, THIRD as 3, FOURTH as 4. And I don't use bind variable. So, the value 2 in the 'NUM2'  can be different in my situation. In short, That value is passed from a process that happened before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `MODEL` clause:

```sql
WITH A ( name, num1 ) AS (
  SELECT 'FIRST',   1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SECOND',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'THIRD',   6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FOURTH', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FIFTH',   2 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT name, num1, num2
FROM   a
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY (ROWNUM AS rn)
  MEASURES ( name, num1, 2 AS num2)
  RULES (
    num2[rn>1] = num1[cv(rn)] * num2[cv(rn)-1]
  )
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> NAME   | NUM1 | NUM2
> :----- | ---: | ---:
> FIRST  |    1 |    2
> SECOND |    3 |    6
> THIRD  |    6 |   36
> FOURTH |   10 |  360
> FIFTH  |    2 |  720
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=643cfa5073fd86d62d32805b8757c028)*

Comment: I just edited this post adding a image. So can you answer this question for me? I think second answer you wrote is a proper answer for this question. Is it right?